# How to prevent UserForm from covering controls on a Worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Using several API calls, I'm positioning a UserForm centered on the screen.
During navigation from this UserForm (a custom "MsgBox" equivalent), I am trying to show the user a button which is located on the sheet behind the UserForm.

Depending on the resolution and size of monitor, the sheet behind the form has different zoom factors, and most of the time the button being highlighted on the sheet is visible.
Sometimes the UserForm completely covers the button.

I have had some success determining whether the form is covering the button, but I'm running into problems which I assume are due to scaling.

```vb
Dim button as Shape
'helpBtnTop is used ByRef to provide the converted measurement
Dim helpBtnTop as Single
Set button = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").Shapes("HelpButton")
'API Call in the following sub uses ConvertPixelsToPoints API to find the top using a conditional string arg
'"Pos" to look at only the Top measurement of the UserForm (left and Right won't matter for this use case).
ReturnPosition button.Top, sngTop:=helpBtnTop, Pos:="Top"

With UserForm
    'My problem is right here - the code itself does not _fail to execute_ but UserForm.Top,
    'button.Top, NOR helpBtnTop match up in any context.  I know some of this
    'has to do with Points vs Pixels, but I'm trying to determine which way I need to go for the
    'proper conversion.  Do I convert the UserForm.Top property to Points?  Are they already in 
    'Points and thus need to be converted back to Pixels?  Or should I be converting the button.Top
    'Property instead, and then calculating from there?
    '

    If .Top >= button.top Then
        .Top = button.top - .Height
    End If

    'For example - I have the top of my UserForm lined up directly in line 
      '(as close to pixel perfect as I can get) with the button - the various .Top properties are as follows:
      'UserForm.Top = 379.5
      'button.top = 386.25
      'helpBtnTop = 357.75.
  End With
```

I'll eventually include the `.Height` property of the UserForm in my figuring since I want to make sure the total value of all of the UserForm's area will not block the view of the button, but I would first like to understand what I need to do to compare apples to apples and not oranges.

If I take the top of each object and convert using `ActiveWindow.PointsToPixelsY` for the measurement, I get within 6 units (assuming *Pixels* in this case) to each other, so I would have to do some conversion to each and base the math on that.  Is this my only alternative?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve and you probably have your reasons to want this, but it sounds like bad practice to me from a user's perspective to be honest. If a userform is open then, imho, any buttons the user is going to be directed to, should be on the form itself. Unless it's some kind of an animated user guide or something in which case you can probably hide and then show the userform again when needed

Comment: So - I have a set of buttons on the main worksheet of a workbook we developed to compare sets of data.  One of these buttons is a "?" _help_ button.  At the beginning of the launch for the first time the user registers the tool, there's a series of help diagrams to point out new features, etc.  At the end, there is a custom message box thanking the users for registering.  Upon clicking "NEXT" to continue the message, it tells the user of a button on the main page for them to see the animations/diagrams again. . . Problem is, sometimes this button is covered depending on the resolution in use.